# Should we make the actions of "user" Community more advanced?

Tags: discussion, support, community-user, bumping

I have seen many questions bumped to the homepage by [Community ♦](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). Many of the bumpings are very good: they tell us of unsolved questions which we can't find out in [the set of more than 11k unanswered questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered).

However, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/472689/latex-commands-directories-are-not-set) has just been bumped to the homepage by Community ♦. But that question is clearly answered and the problem is solved (by the OP himself) as the self-answer. Community ♦ recognized it as unsolved though, because the self-answer is not marked as accepted.

The above case is clearly a case when Community ♦'s system runs not correctly.

Therefore I think we should make the "action" of Community ♦ a bit more advanced, or complicated:

1. All question having a self-answer should be marked as "answered".
2. All question having one (or more) answer(s) in which the OP commented something like "Thank you very much" should also be marked as "answered".
3. All question solved in comments should be marked as answered.
   Even more, I think Community ♦ should convert the "answering" comment to an answer if possible.

Comment: One problem with your second suggestion is that some OPs are just kind and thank other people for helping although nothing has been solved...

Comment: You should know that community is a bot in the background. There are no community people reading comments.

Comment: @TeXnician Note: I've found that much of those comments can easily be filtered out by just excluding "thanks" comments that also include "but".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rule for Community here is simple: questions *without upvoted answers* are possible candidates for bumping. In the question you link, the answer has received no upvotes, so it's not regarded as answered: the entire idea of StackOverflow is that *answers are important to more than just the person who asks the question*.

Comment: Small clarification: without upvoted *or accepted* answer. The OP actually could self-answer and accepted it to prevent Community from bumping the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think that an automatism sometimes could be dangerous.

> All question having a self-answer should be marked as "answered".

It may happen that the OP answers with a workaround, but s/he still looking for something better. See here, for example:
[Diagonal arrows consisting of smaller arrows in xymatrix package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/468537/diagonal-arrows-consisting-of-smaller-arrows-in-xymatrix-package).

> All question having one (or more) answer(s) in which the OP commented
>   something like "Thank you very much" should also be marked as
>   "answered".

If the OP says "thank you", it doesn't automatically mean that the solution is perfect for him. S/he may simply thank for any other reason.

> All question solved in comments should be marked as answered. Even
>   more, I think Community ♦ should convert the "answering" comment to an
>   answer if possible.

Instead of marking the question as answered, I totally agree that the comment which solves the problem should be converted into an answer (even if it's trivial, very often trivial answers are the most useful), but doing it automatically is problematic. A question may have many comments, it's very difficult for an automatism to decide upon which one is the actual solution.

Comment: Comment on the first point: if the OP has a workaround which they deem themselves not a good solution to the problem, they should definitely not post this workaround as an answer. Rather, they should add it to the question and say something like: I was able to solve the problem by doing blablabla, but I am not happy with this for these reasons and would like to get a better solution. The other cases I fully agree with you.

Comment: @marmot You're right!